# Plotly Express TreeMap not compatible with Pandas > 2.0.0

Tags: pandas, pip, plotly, version, plotly-express

I am adding a tree map to my dash app. As it is dash I am inclined to use plotly to visualise the TreeMap. However when I execute my code, plotly express is trying to append to a dataframe which is something you can't do beyond pandas 1.5.3

I would like to see if there is a solution that doesn't involve me using the pandas 1.5.3 package instead of pandas >=2.0.0

My plotly-express version is 0.4.1 and here is my code below:

```
import plotly-express as px

def build_treemap(data, cols):
    tree_data = data.groupby(cols).size().reset_index(name='population')
    cols = [px.Constant('all customers')] + cols
    fig = px.treemap(tree_data, path=cols, values='population')
    return fig
```

data is a dataframe and cols are the columns which are part of my treemap hierarchy in the order of least to most granular.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you sample data with which the problem can be reproduced? The plotly express treemap examples here https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/ work for me with pandas 2.0.0 and plotly express 0.4.1